# Interpreting the timestamp info?

Tags: gps, timestamp

From  [this site](http://radar.oreilly.com/2011/04/apple-location-tracking.html), I learned about the "secret" file that stores my gps info.

I tried to open the file, and I got this SQLite DB.

How can I interpret the timestamp info?

[image]

Comment: http://caffeine.shugendo.org/2011/04/21/iphones-and-location-lets-not-get-hysterical/

Comment: http://www.willclarke.net/?p=247

Answer (score 2):

iOS (and Mac OS X) use the [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) epoch, which means that time is recorded as the number of seconds since the first instant of 1-Jan-2001 UTC. The more common Unix epoch is based on 1970 instead. The [difference between the two](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTimeIntervalSince1970) is `978307200` seconds. To convert, add that amount to the values you see.

The Unix [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) mentioned by Shark lists different ways of converting the epoch-seconds to a human-readable date at the bottom of the page. For example, using JavaScript, you convert the seconds to milliseconds and create a Date object. You can see this in a browser by typing the following in the location field:

```
javascript:alert(new Date((978307200+323827707.004303)*1000).toLocaleString())
```

which converts the Date to the local time zone and format, and displays it with an `alert` dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

run the following query

```
SELECT datetime(323827707, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
```

Also you could head to [epochconverter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to search manually